# Self-added mySQL column as wordpress custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a value from a column that I've added myself to the wp_posts table as a custom field.

So right now there is a column called 'shares' which holds an int value and I want that int value to become a custom field in my wordpress installation so I can use it in the range of features with other wordpress plugins such as sorting the posts etc.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin, it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Can you load a value from mysql db?

Comment: Eh, that is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You should not be adding fields to the posts table. 
Instead you should be adding custom post meta, either with code, custom post fields or a plugin like mentioned by Dion.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box